# Onclick event on nav-link to trigger css animation on hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to trigger the css animation on my hamburger icon when clicking on a navlink. The icon itself works fine by clicking on it (changes to X and back to hamburger). I want the X becoming the hamburger again when clicking on a navlink, because for now only the navigation closes, the X stays... 
Below here you can find the code of my hamburger icon

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hamburg">
  <label for="hamburg" class="hamburg">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<style>
  label.hamburg {
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
  }

  input#hamburg {
    display: none
  }

  .line {
    background: #323b46;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 0.4s;
    width: 40px;
  }

  .line:nth-child(1) {
    top: 9px;
  }

  .line:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 20px;
    top: 18px;
    width: 20px;
  }

  .line:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 10px;
    top: 27px;
    width: 30px;
  }

  #hamburg:checked+.hamburg .line:nth-child(1) {
    background: #323b46;
    transform: translateY(10px) rotate(-36deg);
  }

  #hamburg:checked+.hamburg .line:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #hamburg:checked+.hamburg .line:nth-child(3) {
    background: #323b46;
    margin-left: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(36deg);
    width: 40px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: and where is the navlink in your posted html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add onclick to the Nav links

```
<a href="#" onclick="check()">Nav Link checkbox</a> <br>
<a href="#" onclick=" uncheck()">Nav Link uncheck</a>

<script>
function check() {
  document.getElementById("hamburg").checked = true;

}

function uncheck() {
  document.getElementById("hamburg").checked = false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the a newly created div represents your navbar, then you can just do this:

```js
document.getElementById('navbar').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('hamburg').checked = false
});
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  Navbar
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hamburg" checked>
```

When you click on your X icon since you are dealing with a input checkbox element the X will transform to the hamburger icon

Comment: can you please add the navbar code because I don't see it.